# Stored Procedure changing where clause statements

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a question regarding sql statements. Is it possible to make a query this way? I need to filter a where clause that depends what is the value of @user_id.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getUserAddress]
  @user_id int = null
AS

SELECT user_id, state_code, address from UserAddress

IF(@user_id > 10)
BEGIN
 WHERE state_code = 'CA'
END
ELSE
  WHERE address = 'HILLS'
END
```

I tried to do this way but It seems not a standard way.

```
IF(@user_id > 10)
BEGIN
 SELECT user_id, state_code, address from UserAddress WHERE state_code = 'CA'
END
ELSE
   SELECT user_id, state_code, address from UserAddress WHERE address = 'HILLS'
END
```

Please advise what is the best approach for this concept. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: SELECT IF WHERE is the order you should follow, also if you are using MySQL that is, as @jarlh said you need to specify!

Comment: Are only two the conditions? Do you think that you need to add more conditions in the future?

Comment: Yes, I might Add possible conditions on the future

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `begin` after your `else`. Try this:

```
IF(@user_id > 10)
BEGIN
 SELECT user_id, state_code, address from UserAddress WHERE state_code = 'CA'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT user_id, state_code, address from UserAddress WHERE address = 'HILLS'
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify:

```
select 
    user_id, 
    state_code, 
    address 
from 
    UserAddress 
where 
    (@user_id > 10 and state_code = 'CA') or
    (@user_id IS NULL OR (@user_id <= 10 and address = 'HILLS'))
```

If you will add more filter criteria in the future you should be aware of parameter sniffing.

As an aside, creating an index on `(user_id, state_code, address)` will be a covering index for this query.

Comment: this is wrong! if `(address = 'HILLS')` is true the check on `@user_id` is ignored

Comment: This is still not equivalent to what the OP asked (because of the NULL), but is close enough. Reversing my downvote.

Comment: I think my brain must be fried. Thank you to both of you for pointing out the logic flaws (which have been fixed)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a dynamic sql query in the stored procedure.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);
select @sql = 'select * from [UserAddress] ' 
    + stuff((select case when @user_d > 10 
         then 'where state_code= ''CA''' 
         else 'where address = ''Hills''' end  
    for xml path('')), 1,0,'')

 exec(@sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

rather then this use can use case in your where statement:

```
   SELECT user_id, state_code, address from UserAddress WHERE 
   (case when @user_id > 10 then state_code  else address end) 
   = (case when @user_id > 10 then 'CA' else 'HILLS' end)
```

Comment: I like it this way, very smart

Comment: thnks for compliment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT user_id, state_code, address from UserAddress
WHERE 
((WHERE state_code = 'CA') AND (@user_id > 10))
OR
((WHERE address = 'HILLS') AND (@user_id <= 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply...

```
WHERE
    (@user_id > 10 AND state_code = 'CA')
    OR ((@user_id <= 10 OR @user_id IS NULL) AND address = 'HILLS')
```

However, this approach may not produce the best query plan. If that turns out to be a problem, either use separate queries (as you already tried, but fix the syntax error as suggested by [AsheraH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40649539/533120)), or dynamic SQL.

BTW, you can write separate queries more succinctly like this:

```
IF @user_id > 10
   SELECT user_id, state_code, address from UserAddress WHERE state_code = 'CA'
ELSE
   SELECT user_id, state_code, address from UserAddress WHERE address = 'HILLS'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getUserAddress]
  @user_id int = null
AS
BEGIN
Declare @sql nvarchar(5000)
set @sql='SELECT user_id, state_code, address from UserAddress'
IF(@user_id > 10)
BEGIN
 set @sql=@sql+' WHERE state_code = ''CA'''
END
ELSE
 set @sql=@sql+' WHERE address = ''HILLS'''
END

Exec(@sql)
END